# WebAudio API - do nodes without input consume processing power?

Tags: web-audio-api

In the WebAudio API, if I have a delay node connected to a gain node but no oscillator or media source going into the delay node filter, will the filter still consume memory/CPU by virtue of the fact that it's still connected to the gain node? Or does it only consume memory when it receives and emits sound? I ask because I'm working on a WebAudio example where many oscillators are intermittently connected to and disconnected from many delay nodes, and I'm wondering if it would speed up processing if I also disconnected the delay node from the gain whenever it was idle? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is it depends.  If the browser is smart enough to see that the delay node memory is all zeroes, and there's no input connected, then nothing needs to be done.  However, if the delay node memory is not all zeroes, the node is supposed to continue running, even if nothing is connected.  This is so that if the output were connected to the destination, you'll hear the delay signal played out at the appropriate time.

However, Chrome (and probably Safari and Edge) don't behave like this.  If a node is not somehow connected to the destination, no processing is done at all.  If it's later connected, the delay node will output the data as if nothing had happened.